# Laravel 5.6 eager loading nested relationships

Tags: eager-loading, laravel-5.6

My model relationships are as below:

`Beneficiary has-many FamilyMembers`

`Earner is-a FamilyMember`

In plain English, a *Beneficiary* is the one who heads the family. There are *Family Members* and 'some of them' are considered as *Earners* since they brings in income to the family.

```
Beneficiary {id, name}
FamilyMember {beneficiary_id, id, name}
```

I modeled this as:

```
Beneficiary hasMany FamilyMember
FamilyMember belongsTo Beneficiary
Earner hasOne FamilyMember <-- but I think this is wrong
```

My requirement is to get the name of the Earner (Earner->Member->name).

In my controller, `$beneficiary` is available (`implicit binding`). Then I load Family Members as:

```
$beneficiary->load(['familyMembers']);
```

I need to get the list of Earners and the name of Earner from Member model.

I couldn't come up with a correct way of modelling this. If someone can help me how should I arrange the relationships, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so if I got it right.

An earner is a family member so you can't do Earner hasOne FamilyMember

First of all, in simple words, a model is an implementation of a database table.

Since you don't have an earners table, then no need for a model called `Earner`

I have one question just to be clear:
A beneficiary is a family member, and and earner is a family member as well, correct?

Then in my opinion your tables will be:

- `Families`
- `Family_members`
- `Beneficiaries`

In `Families` table:
A family will just have an `id` and a `name`

In `Family_members` table:
A family_member will have `id`, `name`, `family_id`, `is_earner`

In `Benficiaries` table:
A beneficiary will have `id`, `family_id`, `family_member_id`

So with that said, you can control that in `Beneficiaries` table that there should be unique records for `family_id` and `family_member_id` combined, means that this table will hold each family's beneficiary only, and each family should have only 1 record in this table.

For earners, the boolean column `is_earner` will indicate if a `family_member` earns money to the family or not, with this, it will allow many earners per family (which makes sense)

Let me know if you have any further questions or if I got something wrong in your question!

Comment: Yes, keeping a flag in members table to indicate whether he is a Earner is the way to go. I just explained one scenario and I have another 3 cases having same functionality so that I can do the same there as well. Thumbs up for your guidance (Y)